# UnicodeDecodeError Python Error

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to code a python google api. Getting some unicode issues. My really basic PoC so far is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup        
query = "filetype%3Apdf"
url = "http://www.google.com/search?sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q="+query+"&btnG=Search"
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
response = opener.open(url)
data = response.read()
data = data.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
data = data.encode('UTF-8', 'ignore')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print u""+soup.prettify('UTF-8')
```

My traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./google.py", line 22, in <module>
print u""+soup.prettify('UTF-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 48786: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are converting your `soup` tree to `UTF-8` (an encoded byte string), then try to concatenate this to an empty `u''` *unicode* string.

Python will automatically try and *decode* your encoded byte string, using the default encoding, which is `ASCII`, and fails to decode the `UTF-8` data.

You need to explicitly decode the `prettify()` output:

```
print u"" + soup.prettify('UTF-8').decode('UTF-8')
```

The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) explains this better, including about default encodings. I really, really recommend you read Joel Spolsky's [article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) as well.